# How to add content from a text file to a dictionary using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, server, webserver

I am creating a simple translation web server that takes a list of words from a text file and translates what is said in the URL. For example, if the URL is '*[http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate/e2s/hello+world*'](http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate/e2s/hello+world*%27), text of a Spanish translation will appear on the page.

This what I have that starts the server and loads the text file in the console:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 5000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');

  const fs = require('fs')

  fs.readFile('Spanish.txt', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
    let arr = data.split('  ')
    console.log('data')
  })

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

And this is what the text file looks like:

```
...
nation  nacio/n[Noun]
national  nacional
nationalities nacionalidades
nationality nacionalidad
nationalization nacionalizacio/n
...
```

The English word is on the left side and the Spanish word is on the right. The words are separated by a TAB.

How do I read the contents of the file, add the words to a dictionary, and display the translation when a URL like *http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate/e2s/hello+world* is entered?

I think I need to use a for loop, but I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Yes, you need some kind of loop to load the contents of the file, probably into a [`Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). (The loop may not be in **your** code, it could be hidden in a constructor call or method call. Though in this case I'd probably actually write a loop.)

Comment: You are already on the right track with `.split()`, first you would need to split for each line though.